# Problem with connection pooling in dotnetnuke. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

I have an issue with `DNN (dotnetnuke)`
When users start working with my module after a while this error keeps appearing on my `DNN Logs` and DNN doesn't work properly after this problem occurs:

```
2019-05-12 11:34:44,132 [SRVCT38-SITE146][Thread:51][ERROR]
 DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.InvalidOperationException:     
 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection     
from the pool.  
This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in
use and max pool size was reached.
   at     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection     owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions     userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&     connection)
   at     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbCon    nection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,     TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1     retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at PetaPoco.Database.OpenSharedConnection()
   at PetaPoco.Database.ExecuteScalar[T](String sql, Object[] args)
   at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteScalar[T](String     procedureName, Object[] commandParameters)
   at DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.AddScheduleHistory(Int32 ScheduleID,     DateTime StartDate, String Server)
   at     DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.Scheduler.CoreScheduler.AddScheduleHistory(Sch    eduleHistoryItem scheduleHistoryItem)
```

I've read some other questions which this might be the result of not closing database connections correctly, however; We have a `UnitOfWork` module in our framework that deals with database connections and handles query executions. It has a dispose method as well which will close and dispose connection properly.

I don't realize whats causing the issue? Is it my code or there is other problems with one of the internal modules of `DNN`.

This framework with same `UnitOfWork` is currently working in other projects which all of them are using `DNN` and we have never encountered this problem before.

has anyone encountered the same problem with `DNN` and `SQL Connection` ?

Comment: The issue is with the SQLClientConnection using multiple connections.  It is designed to pool multiple connections.  What may solve issue is to put the Connection into a c# Using statement so when you exit the using all the resources are disposed.

Comment: This may be also be a symptom of long-running queries due to blocking or those in need of query and index tuning. Check SQL Server activity during the problem to identify if these issues are the root cause.

Comment: This is typically due to a failure to close connections. For your unit of work pattern how are you leveraging it inside of DNN?  Using statements?